# Encode non-HTML tags with in HTML String

Tags: apex

I have an HTML string like `String strBody = <p><b>Hello <World>!</b></p>`. Now I want to encode only the Non-HTML tags (here '<', '>' with text World in between).

The output I want is `String strUpdated = <p><b>Hello &lt;World&gt;!</b></p>`.

How to achieve this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). How did you acquire this string? Why is the tag content not already escaped?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @DavidReed. We are migrating Richtext FeedComments and some of the comments are like the String pasted. While inserting we are facing INVALID_MARKUP error